# Getting data from audio mixer

Tags: audio, protocols, mixing

I am trying to build an open-source in-ear monitoring system. I have created the UI and was wondering how I would get the channels that are on an audio mixing console so that I can edit the channels and stream them to each musician. Is there a certain protocol that all the mixers use? You can find the project at https://gitlab.com/openstagemix. We would love to have contributors.

Comment: on the spec sheet for your audio mixing console it should say what audio protocols are supported

Comment: I am using a Yamaha tf1 and couldn't find anything in the manual about what protocol they are using. https://usa.yamaha.com/files/download/other_assets/8/392718/tf5_en_rm_v40_i0.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really test whether this is the correct answer as I am trapped in my house during the coronavirus time. But, all mixers use something called OSC which is a protocol between mixers, synthesizers, etc. to computers. You can find more information here http://opensoundcontrol.org/introduction-osc.
Update: 
It's neither! I am going to use the AES67 standard to receive information from my mixer and with that process the audio. This is because my mixer is ethernet capable.